# Manejo de Ficheros

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema. Al momento de escribir y leer y nuevamente escribir en un fichero no se como puedo hacer, me sale un error que no se puede continuar por lo que no el fichero esta siendo usado en otro llamado, entonces, ¿qué debo hacer?

Tengo este código:

```
    FileStream FlujoBinario = new FileStream(ficheros, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter escribe = new BinaryWriter(FlujoBinario, Encoding.ASCII);
    string NombreProducto;
    int CantidadProducto;
    string CostoProducto;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("\nINGRESE LOS DATOS DEL PRODUCTO");
    Console.WriteLine("\nIngrese el nombre del Producto: ");
    NombreProducto = (string)Console.ReadLine();
    escribe.Close();
    FlujoBinario.Close();
    byte aux = 0;
    FileStream FlujoBinario1 = new FileStream(ficheros, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader lee = new BinaryReader(FlujoBinario1, Encoding.ASCII);
    while (lee.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        if (lee.ReadString() == NombreProducto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRODUCTO YA INGRESADO");
            Console.ReadKey();
            aux = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            lee.ReadString();
            lee.ReadInt32();
            lee.ReadString();

        }

    if (aux == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Producto no encontrado");
    }
    lee.Close();
    FlujoBinario.Close();
    }
    FlujoBinario = new FileStream(ficheros, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter escribe1 = new BinaryWriter(FlujoBinario, Encoding.ASCII);
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de producto que tiene en Stock: ");
    CantidadProducto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el costo del producto C/u");
    CostoProducto = (string)Console.ReadLine();
    escribe1.Write(CantidadProducto);
    escribe1.Write(CostoProducto);
    escribe1.Close();
    FlujoBinario1.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n PRESIONE UNA TECLA PARA REGRESAR AL MENU");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Parece ser que dentro del while que dice "lee.PeekChar()" cierras el archivo antes de salir del while.

Comment: Como bien dice @Luis, `FlujoBinario.Close();` debería estar fuera del bucle `while`